# How to run two python3 file with both file using the same Raspberry Pi Camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, raspberry-pi

I have two python3 file

#1 Facemask recognition (Deep Learning)

#2 QR Code scanner (Machine Learning)

Im using Raspberry Pi 3 B+ & 8 MP single Pi Cam

Both program does not have any connection, however I need to run both at the same time to detect someone who mask or not AND to scan QR code of user

The problem is I found conflict on pi camera because I only use one pi camera for two different program. Plus, facemask using videostream while QR Scan using videocaptures.

Hope someone can help me on pi camera conflict with two python3 file that using it.

Below is my code:

#1 Facemask Recognition based on Github

https://github.com/manish-1305/facemask_detection/blob/73f37f724b519731eec7d46cb4a23482147db24b/detect.py

#2 QR Code Scanner

```
import cv2
import re
from time import time
import datetime
import board


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

def sw1Pressed():
    global sw1Press
    sw1Press = True

sw1.when_pressed = sw1Pressed
sw1Press = False


print("Press SW1 to scan.")


while True:
    if sw1Press == True:
        led.toggle()
        
        _, img = cap.read()
        data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
        
        if bbox is not None:
            for i in range(len(bbox)):
                cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i+1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255,
                         0, 0), thickness=2)
                
            cv2.putText(img, data, (int(bbox[0][0][0]), int(bbox[0][0][1]) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            
            if data:
                sw1Press = False
                
                data = data.split(",")
                print("ID: " + data[0])
                print("NAME: " + data[1])
               
                print()
                
                userScanned = False
                with open('XXX.csv') as csvfile:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                    for row in reader:
                        if row["ID"] == data[0]:
                            buzzer.beep(0.1, 0.1, 1)
                            userScanned = True
                    
                if userScanned == False:
                    buzzer.beep(0.1, 0.1, 2)
                    with open('XXX.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                        fieldNames = ['ID', 'NAME']
                        
                        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldNames)
                        writer.writerow({'ID': data[0], 'NAME': data[1]})
                        
                currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                
                print("Date & Time: {}".format(currentTime))
                print()
                
                data = {
                'ID' : data[0],
                'NAME' : data[1],
                
                'TIME' : currentTime,
               
                }
                
        cv2.imshow("code detector", img)
    
    else:
        cap.read()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

led.off()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one program (or thread) that reads the camera continuously and stores the picture somewhere the two clients (mask and QR) can read it.

In practical terms that could be:

- one program with 3 threads, one thread reading from camera into shared Numpy array, and two threads reading from that shared array, or
- three programs, one reading images into a Python v3.8 [multiprocessing shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) and two programs attaching to that shared memory to read frames
- three programs, perhaps on different machines, one reading frames from the camera and throwing them into [Redis](https://redis.io) and the other two reading frames out of **Redis**

Comment: Sir, how about im using webcam as second camera? But I dont know how to setup the program so that it can use Pi Cam or Webcam at different task. Pi Cam = Facemask & Webcam = QR Code Read

Comment: If you have a question about a second camera, just ask another question - they are free - answers are free too. Be sure to say what camera it is and how it is connected.